# Rake aborted, no rake file found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey people i know maybe 1% of ruby and need many help...

I migrated a system from one server to another server

When I try to insert an entry to the database using the system, I get the following error (remembering that I use ruby is 2.1):

```
   undefined method `insert_record' for #<Array:0x007fec2a2b2fa0>
```

i know maybe this is a solution:

http://alok-anand-ror.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/undefined-method-insertrecord-for.html

i have gems of rake instaled 0.9.2 and 0.9.2.2

when i try run "rake db:migrate" (I think it would solve, I do not know) i received

**rake aborted No rake file found**

if somebody can help me  I greatly appreciate.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Seems like you have 2 completely different issues at hand. One is the `insert_record` issue. The other is running `rake db:migrate`. Are you running the rake command from a folder with a Rakefile? as for the `insert_record` issue, can't tell much without seeing the code that you're trying to execute other than Arrays do not response to `insert_record`

Comment: As I said i know minimum of ruby, almost nothing, I run this command inside rake gems folder and the root folder of aplication and in app/config/initializers with rb called i created ActiveRecord.rb. How do I know if there is a file of type rake?

Comment: make sure that `ls Rakefile` is show you it. then issue `rake -T|grep migrate` to see the wheither the task is present

Comment: according the `#insert_record`, provide a piece of code when the error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems your Rakefile is missing .
Check your rails folder should contain Rakefile with following content

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
 # Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
 # for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.
 require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

  Demo::Application.load_tasks
~
```

and

```
undefined method `insert_record' for #<Array:0x007fec2a2b2fa0>
```

this error is because of  incompatibility issues with rails and ruby , try upgrading rails

Comment: Anil Maurya, necessarily need to upgrade the rails to work? some especific version?

Comment: @André its Good to upgrade and work on latest stable version . upgrade to Rails 4.0

Comment: thanks to Leo Correa,Малъ Скрылевъ and Anil Maurya, instaled new rails all work!!!